# MVC3 strange hidden value missing during PartialView Ajax Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I'm having a very strange issue when rendering a partial view.  My page has a table whose rows are rendered using a partial view.  Here's a snippet

```
<td>
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/edit_icon.gif")" class="editLine" />
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/delete_icon.gif")" class="deleteLine" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LineId)
</td>
```

This renders fine when the page first loads.  The input tags have the value set to the id.  However, when I do an ajax call and return the PartialView from the controller, this value is always 0.

Controller code:

```
line.LineId = 12; //whatever the actual value is
return PartialView("Line", line);
```

And the jquery code is

```
$.ajax({
        data: {
            Id: id
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {

           $('#lines').append(data);

        }
```

When I debug through and look I see data has come back as

```
<input name="lineId" id="lineId" value="0" />
```

I debugged through EVERYTHING and the lineId is not 0.  I then debugged throuh the view itself and whenever I did Html.Hidden("lineId", anyvalueHere) it rendered as 0.  When I changed it to be Html.Hidden("lineId_" + actualId, actualId) it worked.

Is this known/expected behavior? I can imagine it not jiving with duplicate id's.  However, it renders just fine on the page load where I use the exact same partial view.  Is there magical juju for client side stuff?  I would imagine not since it's just a controller action and it doesn't know the difference.  Has anyone seen this.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are changing the value when you post, that is the issue.  Use:

```
<input type='hidden' name='LineId' value='<%: Model.LineId %>'/>
```

instead of the Html.HiddenFor.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  I suppose there are already hidden fields with that id on the form.  I don't see how the controller would know where the call came from and if the values were already set.

Comment: If you post something from the form and change it inside your controller, when you re-render the page using the Html helpers it will use the value which was originally posted to the action.

Comment: I can understand if it were a server post.  But this is a client side post...how the heck does it even know.  I'm not discounting your solution because you're right.  I just don't get it

Comment: When you call that ajax it does a post to the server.  It adds the appropriate headers on the client and the server sees those so it knows what type of request you are sending.

Comment: Right, but how does it know the initial value or that the value changed or anything like that.

Comment: Ahh, well I don't know the MVC internals but I am guessing that it checks the Form collection in the HttpRequest.